# JTree: Por que ela perde foco quando eu edito um nó?

Tags: java, jtree

Estou desenvolvendo um componente PJC (Oracle Forms).
Estou criando um Bean com um JTree dentro dele.
Numa aplicação padrão java, funciona bem, mas no PJC ocorre um comportamento estranho com o foco.
Quando pressiono F2 ou um *click* longo para editar um nó da árvore, o editor perde o foco. Então, em vez de simplesmente começar a digitar o novo valor, eu tenho que clicar manualmente no editor e só então consigo mudar o valor.
Não sei porque isso acontece e como evitar.
Tentei gerar um *log* dos eventos de foco:

```
Tree focusLost e.getOppositeComponent: org.jdesktop.swingx.tree.DefaultXTreeCellEditor$XEditorContainer
Tree focusLost e.paramString: FOCUS_LOST,permanent,opposite=org.jdesktop.swingx.tree.DefaultXTreeCellEditor$XEditorContainer[,38,160,100x16]
Tree focusLost e.getSource: org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTree
```

Alguém sabe como evitar que o editor perca o foco?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver.

Lembrando que normalmente não há este problema, aconteceu por estar dentro de um VBean (Containter PJC/Oracle Forms).

Precisei criar um editor, usei o JTextField:

```
this.textField = new JTextField();
this.textField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red, 1));
this.cellEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(this.textField);
this.tree.setCellEditor(new treeCellEditor(this.tree, this.cellRenderer, this.cellEditor));
```

Na minha classe do editor, sobrescrevi o método prepareForEditing, forçando a pegar o foco.

```
private class treeCellEditor extends DefaultTreeCellEditor {
    public treeCellEditor(JTree tree, DefaultTreeCellRenderer renderer, TreeCellEditor editor) {
        super(tree, renderer, editor);
    }
    public treeCellEditor(JTree tree, DefaultTreeCellRenderer renderer) {
        super(tree, renderer);
    }
    protected void prepareForEditing() {
        super.prepareForEditing();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                textField.requestFocusInWindow();
                textField.grabFocus();
                textField.selectAll();
            }
        });
    }
}
```